# select() loop not working with TPACKET_V3

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, pcap

My user-space application needs to listen on multiple interfaces for capturing raw packets. For that, I am using pcap raw capture APIs. Also I am making the descriptors returned from *pcap_create* selectable using *pcap_get_selectable_fd*.  These descriptors are further subscribed to the select() loop for read using FD_SET.

The issue here is although I am subscribing to the select() for mulitple interfaces, the application is only getting packets for the first interface subscribed.

For the rest of the interfaces, I can see that the packets are reaching those interfaces using tcpdump. But for some reason, it is not picked up from the select() loop in my application.

Going further into the pcap library, I found that the issue is related to TPACKET_V3 support for the pcap captures. If I disable the TPACKET_V3 support and use TPACKET_V2, everything works fine. Packets from all the interfaces are reading from the select loop.

I do not know if this is some known issue with the TPACKET_V3, but I really want the performance boost of TPACKET_V3 in my application. I would like to know if I can use the select() loop with TPACKET_V3 support enabled.

Kernel version: 2.6.33
LibPcap version: 1.0.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the LibPcap version 1.0.0 does not have   
TPACKET_V3 support .It starts from 1.5.0 .Please refer to the following   links https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues/169.  https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-48/libpcap/CHANGES

Comment: @achoora It is really a matter of kernel support and not libpcap. If the linux kernel supports TPACKET_V3, then we can activate it on the created socket using setsockopt()

Comment: The 2.6.33 kernel doesn't have TPACKET_V3 support, either.  [It was added in 3.2](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.2).  So, with a 2.6.33 kernel and libpcap 1.0.0, this is definitely ***NOT*** an issue with TPACKET_V3.  If you were able to disable TPACKET_V3 support in libpcap and rebuild libpcap, you were ***NOT*** doing so with libpcap 1.0.0 - what version of libpcap *were* you using?  And what kernel version were you really using?

Comment: Yes, 2.6.33 kernel does not have TPACKET_V3. But I am using a customized kernel where it has the TPACKET_V3 support backported from 3.2 kernel. So, it is where I am seeing this issue. The libpcap version is  1.0.0. Is there any known fixes from 3.2 kernel where it resolves this ?